# MySQLdb SELECT with executemany() equivalents

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

So it seems well discussed and documented that `executemany()` is intended for operations like INSERTs and UPDATEs. Calling `cursor.executemany(...)` on a list of dictionaries and reading in `cursor.fetchall()` seems to only return an item from a single execute.

To achieve the same result, the general solution seems to be to formulate a single query with the select items like `SELECT FROM books WHERE title IN ('booka', 'bookb', 'bookc', ...)`, but it seems this would run into issues at-scale, say hundreds of thousands of items. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

The most obvious solution from there may be to batch the queries such that the IN predicates are a reasonable length, but that seems like a lot of hand-holding to make sure each packet is of a reasonable size.

**Are there other features in MySQLdb that I'm overlooking that would return a list of results, given a dictionary of input values?**

This gets particularly interesting when I'm trying to match against sets of tuples, e.g. (book, author), not just single values.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Can you give more example?

Comment: A way to pass a dict of values to SELECT on (similar to how executemany() accepts a dict of values to use for an INSERT / UPDATE) that will send multiple transactions instead of dumping a large number (~100k) values into an IN predicate, like the book example above, which could run into other issues like exceeding packet size limits.

Comment: @JustianMeyer : Were you able to resolve the issue? i am also facing the same issue. I need to execute select query with 1000 items in the list, something like SELECT FROM books WHERE title IN ('book1', 'book2', 'book3', ...'book1000'),  This is taking too long comparatively.